# Django get returns ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <string>

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.car}-{self.name}"
```

Here is some code I tried in shell that is returning some unexpected results

from models import Model

```
print(Model.objects.all())
```

returns

```
<QuerySet [<Model: Toyota-Previa>, <Model: Toyota-Supra>, `<Model: Toyota-Camery>, <Model: Ford-Torous>, <Model: Ford-Mustang>, <Model: Ford-GT>, <Model: Mercedes-SLR>,` 
<Model: Mercedes-AMG>, <Model: Mercedes-C-Class>]>
```

but

```
print(Model.objects.get(car = 'Toyota'))
```

returns

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Toyota'.
```

I don't understand why this happens, I thought this would return a queryset that gives all of the cars made by Toyota in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `car` field in `Model` is ForeignKey, stored integer value as id of `Car` model. You can get Model record by using this query:

```
print(Model.objects.get(car__name='Toyota'))
```